# Visual Studio separate color of integral type and modifier

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, color-scheme

In MonoDevelop the color of integral types (`int`, `string`) and modifiers (`public`, `abstract`) have separate color values. In Visual Studio, however, they are all (along with `true`/`false`) grouped together under *Keywords*.

Is there any modification or something that can be made, or anywhere to complain to Microsoft where they'll actually listen?

Comment: Your question is arguably off-topic for SO sadly

Comment: Your complain might hurt many Visual Studio users who loves it that way :)

Comment: I took out the off topic things @MickyDuncan

Comment: And, no Rahul Singh, it would not hurt anyone to have more options available... I prefer it the way it is, but my friend, who's trying to get into coding, really doesn't like it that way. So far as to not want to use visual studio because of it.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012, 2013, and 2015 do not have the modifiers and intrinsic types separated.  Both are colored via the Keywords setting.

You can request new features via the [Visual Studio User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) site.

If you feel like writing a Visual Studio extension, you might be able to code something up.  Before I went down that road I'd look to see if anyone had already done it.